# Strange HTML code after Jekyll build

Tags: ruby, build, jekyll, liquid

After building my site, this strange code is created before included content.

﻿

The problem is that it causes a white line before included content

For example: my layout

```
{% include static/header.html %}
<div id="wrapper">
{% include static/left.html %}
<div id="main">
{% include static/functions.html %}
{% include static/workflow.html %}
<div id="article">
{{content}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

will return in firebug HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
&#65279;<div id="left">
<img src="images/static/left.png" />
</div>
<div id="main">
&#65279;<img src="images/static/functions001.png" />
&#65279;<img src="images/static/workflow001.png" />
<div id="article">
&#65279;<p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

while in notepad++ I can see black dots at the beginning of the line.
screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b84mC.png

Comment: This doesn’t look like a Ruby on Rails question, do you think it should have the `ruby` tag rather than `ruby-on-rails`?

Comment: I will fix, adding the "liquid" tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's you text editor which puts BOM.

Open your file in notepad++ then **Encoding->encoding UTF-8 without BOM** then save it.

Comment: Already got this problem. It's now definitely resolved as I'm full Linux ;-)

Comment: So it's Windows' fault! My coworker uses jekyll on a Mac and he doesn't have this issue. Unix rules :-)

Comment: It is not Windows' fault. It is the setting in Notepad++ that caused this. Most Windows editors would do this correctly too and editors in Linux or some other Unix derivate can do it wrong too.